# How to change which file types Windows Photo Viewer show when navigating to Previous or Next

Tags: windows-photo-viewer

If you open a photo in Windows Photo Viewer and press the right arrow, it will move to the next photo in the folder. However, it will skip any non-photo file types (e.g. txt, doc, xls). It will include image types (jpg, png, tif, etc.)

Where can I control which types are included? The aim is to <s>include</s> **exclude** raw files from my camera (.orf) which are currently being included. (Note that orf files are not currently associated to be opened by Photo Viewer)

**EDIT:** the reason for doing this is that I take pictures with my camera in Raw+JPEG mode and both end up in the same folder, but when browsing with Windows Photo Viewer I don't want to see every photo twice.

Comment: I'm guessing that OP meant "excluded". If so, why not just associate the file type?

Comment: To have them included will probably require a "coded" for the file type (there is one such for Nikon NEF files).

Comment: @Hannu You mean "codec" (damn you autocorrect, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall **Microsoft Camera Codec Pack** to make **Windows Photo Viewer** skip RAW file types just like it skips non-image file types

Windows Photo Viewer cannot read RAW files unless you install [Codecs](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows7/how-do-i-view-raw-pictures).

**EDIT** : *If you have not installed Microsoft Camera Codec Pack but installed a third party program that allows viewing RAW files, you would need to uninstall it*

Comment: I never installed the Camera Codec Pack. I just checked in Control Panel, Uninstall a program, and it does not appear in the list. I'm using Windows 8.1 Pro.

Comment: Ok, I found the culprit. I had FastPictureViewer Pro installed on my PC, and apparently that was supplying the codecs (which didn't actually work, as Windows Photo Viewer was displaying an error message "can't display file" anyway). After I uninstalled FastPictureViewer, the orf files stopped being included by Windows Photo Viewer.

Comment: Ahh this was almost starting to get on my nerves :/ I have picassa installed on my computer but it doesn't cause the kind of behavior as with FastPictureViewer

Answer (score 1):

You must install [Microsoft Camera Codec Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=26829)

This will allow you to view/preview Olympus Raw Format **(.orf files)** in Windows Photo Viewer

**Note :** You might also need to associate **.orf** file type with **Windows Photo Viewer**

You can refer to [this](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/9154-default-programs-associate-file-type-protocol.html) for the instructions

Comment: Sorry, fixed the typo. I am trying to **exclude** raw files.

Comment: Hmm is it because .orf files don't open in window's photo viewer ? I will try post another answer after some hair snatching though

Comment: Thanks. Actually it's because I shoot RAW+JPEG but I only want to see Jpegs because I don't want to see every photo twice. (And can't move them to a different folder due to the way I manage the files in Adobe Lightroom)

Comment: @Laurent, just started to stumble upon your question, and just by uninstalling **Microsoft Camera Codec Pack** i can skip .CR2 file types. You should be able to skip .orf file types too